# XMLHttpRequest GET not working in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest

I have  a `Profile` class, like this :

```
 class Profile extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        userName: '',
        userID: ''
    };

    getData() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/user/1');
        request.send();
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            div >
            this.getData(); <
            /div>

        );
    }
}
```

The problem is it is not putting anything in the console.

Although `http://localhost:8080/user/1` in browser returning me this :

`{"userID":1,"passwordHash":"5994471abb01112afcc18159f6cc74b4f511b99806da59b3caf5a9c173cacfc5","email":"admin@admin.com"}`

[image: user/1]

**How to resolve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could manage to solve your issue, You need to wrap function calling with `{this.getData();}`

An example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abimaran/5zox4mdj/20/)

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
   constructor(props)   {
      super(props);
      this.state = {email:'', userName:'', userID:''};
   }

   getData() {
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     console.log("Inside getData method");

     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
     };
     request.open('GET', 'https://reqres.in/api/products/3', true);
     request.send();
     console.log(request.responseText);
   }

   render() {
    return(
     <div>
      <h2>You sample output</h2>
        {this.getData()}
      </div>
    );
   }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Profile />, document.querySelector("#container"))
```

Comment: This looks more appropriate to me, as this uses `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 1):

You should populate data with AJAX calls in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. This is so you can use setState to update your component when the data is retrieved.

Example from react documentation

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      userName: '',
      userID: '',
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

 fetch("http://localhost:8080/user/1")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            email: result.email,
            userName: result.userName,
            userID: result.userID
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, email, userName, userID  } = this.state;
    return (
        <ul>
          {email}
          {userName}
          {userID}
        </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Because you are mapping the object not an array. This is just an exampe

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad just update my answer you can check again